# Implimenting half angle bisector with single input

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, geometry

I want to implement this function to divide an angle but my math knowledge is very limited so I need help.

In practice and in programming only the lengths of the horizontal or vertical lines are available and easy to calculate.

my question is it possible to make this calculation with only one data
WZ which is horizon line

[image]

Comment: To determine the angle you need two lines.

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to calculate, `Y` has the coordinates `(WZ, 6)` per the image, the line from `W` trough `Y` is the bisector. The angle can be computed via `atan2(6,WZ)`

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Long answer:

If XY == YZ:

```
bisected = arcsin(YZ/(YZ^2+WZ^2))
```

If XY != YZ:

```
bisected = 1/2*(arcsin(XY/(XY^2+WZ^2))+arcsin(YZ/(YZ^2+WZ^2)))
```

You'll need to know at least XZ and WZ to calculate the bisected angle.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying.

Yes it's easy to calculate it with the trigonomic function... since WZ is a horizontal line so by selecting any arbitrary point on WX to find the acrtan then divide it by 2

```
arctan(tangent of any point on WX)/2
```

I want to solve it with linear algebra and find the equations of the lines

Comment: Not an answer - make comment to Minh's answer and delete this one.